# Prevent "input" function from calling functions or accessing variables

Tags: matlab, input, user-input

Considering the following code

```
x = input('Input an array: ');
```

If the user types `[1 2 3]`, variable `x` will be assigned that numeric vector. Similarly, if they type `{1, [2 3], 'abc'}`, variable `x` will be a cell array containing those values. Fine.

Now, if the user types `[sqrt(2) sin(pi/3)]`, variable `x` will be assigned the resulting values: `[1.414213562373095 0.866025403784439]`. That's because the provided data is **evaluated** by [`input`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html):

> `input` Prompt for user input. 
> `result = input(prompt)` displays the `prompt` string on the screen, waits
> for input from the keyboard, **evaluates any expressions in the input**,
> and returns the value in `result`. [...]

This can cause problems. For example, what happens if the user types `addpath('c:\path\to\folder')` as input? Since the input is evaluated, it's actually a
command which will be executed by Matlab. So the user can get to add a folder to the path. Worse yet, if they input `path('')`, the path will be effectively changed to nothing, and Matlab will stop working properly.

Another potential source of problems is that

> [...] To evaluate expressions, `input` **accesses variables in the current workspace**.

For example, if the user inputs `fprintf(1,'%f', varname)` and `varname` is an existing numeric array, the user will know its current value.

This behaviour is probably by design. Users of a Matlab program are trusted when inputting data, much like they are trusted not to press <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to halt the program (and then issue all commands or inspect all variables they like!).

But in certain cases the programmer may want to have a more "secure" `input` function, by which I mean

1. **prevent any function calls when evaluating user
   input**; and
2. **prevent the input from accessing variables of the program**.

So `[1 2]` would be valid input, but `[sqrt(2) sin(pi/3)]` or `path('')` would not because of item 1; and `[1 2 3 varname(1)]` would be invalid too because of item 2.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! If it is only about reading an array of numbers, you could again read the input as string, and use `str2num` on the string. Or would there be any other drawbacks with that approach?

Comment: @hbaderts For that particular case (array of numbers) I think that would be a very good approach: simple and effective. It won't work for more general input, though (cell arrays, char arrays etc)

Comment: Are any operations, e.g. *,+,-,/ etc valid?  Or do you only want numbers, text or a combination of numeric and char (stored in a cell)?  Should all text be enclosed in `'`?

Comment: Operations are valid, but a solution in which they are not valid is fine too. Arrays will be combinations of numbers, logical values, chars; whether "standard" arrays or cell arrays. Examples: `[1 2 3]`, `{1 2 'abc'}`, `['ABC' 68]`, `[1+cos(2) 2]`(not valid: there's a function call), `{'cos(1)' 'sin(1)'}` (valid: they are strings)

Comment: I assume you're familiar with little  Bobby Tables?   Failure to do input validation is always a BadThing(TM) .   I can't imagine why (ok, yes I can)  MathWorks allowed stuff like this to get into production.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes, I read about that at xkcd :-) The thing is, `input`'s documentation recognizes it works that way. So it seems to be a feature, not a bug. Anyway, it would be nice that Matlab included a "secure input" function. It seems they have already done most of the work in `getcallinfo`

Comment: I need to add to this discussion. Note that all circumstances where you would use `input`, the user can Ctrl+C stop the program and run arbitrary commands on the MATLAB command line. There is no need to protect a MATLAB installation against a MATLAB user.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I agree (see the third-to-last paragraph in my question)

Comment: @LuisMendo: sorry, didn’t see that part. I was reacting to the short-sighted comment by Carl “I can't imagine why (ok, yes I can) MathWorks allowed stuff like this to get into production.”

Answer (score 7):

I have found a not very satisfactory solution (and I'd love to read about a better one). It uses a **semi-documented** function and implies saving the user input to a **temporary file**. The function, referred to in [Yair Altman's blog](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/function-definition-meta-info), is `getcallinfo`. According to `help getcallinfo`:

> `getcallinfo`
>
> Returns **called functions** and their first and last lines 
>       This function is unsupported and might change or be removed without
>       notice in a future version.

This function solves issue 1 (prevent function calls). As for issue 2 (prevent access to variables), it would suffice to evaluate the input within a function, so that it can't see other variables. Apparently (see example 2 below), `getcallinfo` detects not only called functions, but **variables too**. Anyway, it's probably a good idea to do the evaluation in the isolated scope of a function.

The procedure is then:

1. Use the string version of `input` to prevent evaluation:

   ```
   x = input('Input an array: ', 's');
   ```
2. Save the string to a file:

   ```
   filename = 'tmp.m';
   fid = fopen(filename,'w');
   fprintf(fid, '%s',x);
   fclose(fid);
   ```
3. Check the input string with `getcallinfo` to detect possible function calls:

   ```
   gci = getcallinfo(filename);
   if ~isempty(gci.calls.fcnCalls.names)
       %// Input includes function calls: ignore / ask again / ...
   else
       x = evalinput(x); %// evaluate input in a function
   end
   ```

where `evalinput` is the following function

```
function x = evalinput(x)
x = eval(x);
```

#### Example 1

Consider

```
x = input('Input an array: ', 's');
```

with user input

```
[sqrt(2) sin(pi/3)]
```

Then

```
filename = 'tmp.m';
fid = fopen(filename,'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s',x);
fclose(fid);
gci = getcallinfo(filename);
```

produces a non-empty `gci.calls.fcnCalls.names`,

```
>> gci.calls.fcnCalls.names
ans = 
    'sqrt'    'sin'    'pi'
```

which tells us that the user input would call functions `sqrt`, `sin` and `pi` if evaluated. Note that operators such as `/` are not detected as functions.

#### Example 2

```
y = [10 20 30];
x = input('Input an array: ', 's');
```

User enters

```
[1 y y.^2]
```

Then

```
filename = 'tmp.m';
fid = fopen(filename,'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s',x);
fclose(fid);
gci = getcallinfo(filename);
```

produces

```
>> gci.calls.fcnCalls.names
ans = 
    'y'    'y'
```

So variables are detected by `getcallinfo` as if they were functions.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks! Yair Altman's blog is an amazing source of weird stuff :-)

Comment: Just wondering:  if you build a dialog box with `inputdlg` , there's a config option  `options.Interpreter` .  Can this be used to force input to be treated as either numeric or string (and thus NOT a function or path call)?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That option seems to control rendering of the _prompt_ string (tex or plain) http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputdlg.html

Comment: Any reason why you cannot use regex or some pattern matching to identify approved vs. non-approved strings, then evaluate them if they pass?

Comment: @pragmatist1 I thought about that when I was dealing with this problem a few days ago. At first glance it seemed complicated. The regexp should be able to identify when a function name is within a string, and ignore it in that case. But pehaps it's simpler thab I thought: a potential function name is within a string if and only if it has an  odd number of quote signs to the left. It's a promising approach. Care to write an answer about that? If you don't, maybe I'll look into that in the future. Thanks for the suggestion in any case!

Comment: I'll give it a stab later tonight. Is it safe to assume that rules 1 and 2 you've listed above are the only ones? Also it is not clear to me: are you rejecting any invalid input, or are you "cleaning it up" and removing the function calls?

Comment: @pragmatist1 Great! No hurry of course. Well, those rules are the only ones I could think of as being important. So in principle yes. The idea is to prevent malicuous input, meaning input that could _execute_ something or _inspect_ the program state when being evaluated. If you think some other rule would have to be included for that, please do it

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, it is possible to use regular expressions to accomplish what you are trying to do.

**No function or variable calls**

At its simplest, this checks to making sure there are no alphabetical characters in the input string. The expression would then be, for `x` containing input:

```
expr = '[a-zA-Z]';
x = input('Input an array: ', 's');
valid = isempty(regexp(x,expr));
```

This alone works for the few examples you give above.

**Allowing some functions or variables**

Suppose you want to allow the user to access some variables or functions, maybe simple trig functions, or `pi` or what have you, then it's no longer so simple. I've been playing around with an expression like below:

`expr = '(?!cos\(|pi|sin\()[a-zA-Z]+`

But it doesn't quite do what is expected. It will match `in(` in `sin`. If you know regex better than I, you can massage that to work properly.

Otherwise, an alternative would be to do this:

```
isempty(regexp(regexprep(x,'(sin\(|cos\(|pi|x)',''),expr))
```

so that you remove the strings you are interested in.

Hope this helps.

**Update: In order to allow imaginary/exp values, and paths**

The new expression to match becomes

```
expr = '[iIeE][a-zA-Z]+';
```

This ignores i/I and e/E (you can augment this as you see fit). You can also do a two character limit by switching to `\{2,}`, though I people can still have one character anonymous functions..

The other part, to check for input becomes:

```
isempty(regexp(regexprep(x,'(sin\(|cos\(|pi|x|''(.*?)'')',''),expr))
```

now you can exclude custom functions (you can always have this as an array and join them together by a `|`) and paths.

Here are a few examples tested along with the usual:

**Passes**

```
'[1+2i, 34e12]'
'''this is a path'''
'[cos(5), sin(3+2i)]'
```

**Fails**

```
'[1+2ii, 34e12]'
'this is not a path'
'''this is a path'' this is not'
```

Comment: Thanks. You should allow characters `e`, `E`, `i`, `j`, so that numbers such as `-1.2e-3j` are accepted. I think a good criterion to screen functions could be to forbid _two_ alphabetic characters together. Also, things like `'Fear is the path to the dark side'` should be allowed too (`path` appears but is within within a string)

Comment: Ah yes, I don't know why that didn't cross my mind. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok I updated it. Let me know if it needs changing. I'm not regex guru, but hopefully this does the job!

Comment: Actually I don't want to remove the bad parts from the string, just to detect if the string contains at least one such bad part (and reject the whole string in that case). So I think something like `regexp(x, '^[^'']*(''[^'']*''[^'']*)*[a-zA-Z]{2}')` works (gives non-empty if the string has two letters together outside of a string). I'll have to do more thorough testing, but it's promising.

Comment: Yes, my use regexprep was not to sanitize a string, but to remove potentially allowed functions/variables before running the general expression against it. Either case, hopefully it works out for you!